# Integration of microsoft test manager with TFS for Bug management

Tags: tfs

Currently we are using TFS (Web Version) as we know a product backlog item can be added via 1-Product backlog Item 2-Bug (We are using Bug to keep track of Customer/partner logged bugs)

When ever we post a bug from MTM its visible in the product backlog list (Which we don't want)

1. Is there any alternates for this?
2. Can we create one more menu under the Backlogs tab?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWzVw.jpg)

Comment: Why  don'tyou want all bugs on the backlog?

Answer (score 0):

You should really create a  separate work item type, maybe "Issue", to represent an externally reported issue.

You can then triage those issues and break them down into Bugs and PBI's that then appear on the backlog for ordering.

Try and avoid the Bug as a task Anti-Pattern: https://nkdagility.com/avoid-bug-task-anti-pattern-tfs/

However you can also configure TFS to treat Bugs as Tasks, and thus they never apear on the board. Go to  the Backlog and click the lower cog to configure this.

You an then create a custom "Issue" work item type for the reported stuff and add it to be shown on the Backlog.

You  will need to edit the process template for this.